# ffmpeg in cocoa app does not do perfect streaming

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ffmpeg, libav

I am using ffmpeg 3.1.4
If i stream via command line on Mac 10.10.5 its done properly.

However when i compile source code and add library files in my cocoa app and try to stream i get errors.

Format context is created properly using :

```
avformat_alloc_output_context2(_avOutputFormatContext, _avOutputFormat, "flv", "rtmp://path/swati.flv"
```

File is opened properly :

```
avio_open(&_avOutputFormatContext->pb, cStreamName, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
```

However Error is received at :

```
avformat_write_header(_avOutputFormatContext, NULL);
```

It gives -22 error

Any suggestion what should i do.

Comment: Without knowing what formats you're using there's likely not an answer to your question...

Comment: Since there no whole code is available, Can't say in detail but you are passing wrong/invalid argument to `avformat_write_header`. Check whether `_avOutputFormatContext` is initialized properly